# Multiple check boxes in wordpress metabox

Tags: php, wordpress, save, meta-boxes

**how to multiple check boxes in word press meta box array?**

In my case, my single checkbox works properly, but my multiple check boxes doesn't work, that just save last item.

I have some problems in Save Meta box and show meta box.

I'm failing to understand how to use:

```
get_post_meta()
checked()
update_post_meta()
```

The Code:

```
        <?php
    class Canco_Meta_Box {

        protected $_meta_box;

        function __construct( $meta_box ) {

            $this->_meta_box = $meta_box;

            add_action( 'admin_menu', array( &$this, 'add_meta_box' ) );
            add_action( 'save_post', array( &$this, 'save_meta_box' ) );

        }

        function add_meta_box() {

            foreach ( $this->_meta_box['pages'] as $page ) {
                add_meta_box( $this->_meta_box['id'], $this->_meta_box['title'], array( &$this, 'show_meta_box'  ), $page, $this->_meta_box['context'], $this->_meta_box['priority'] );
            }

        }

        function show_meta_box( $post ) {

            echo '<input type="hidden" name="canco_meta_box_nonce" value="', wp_create_nonce( basename( __FILE__ ) ), '" />';

            foreach ( $this->_meta_box['fields'] as $field ) {
                $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $field['id'], true );
                $this->meta_box_fields( $field, $value );
            }

        }

        function save_meta_box( $post_id ) {

            global $post;

            if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['canco_meta_box_nonce'], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) {
                return $post_id;
            }

            if ( ! empty( $_POST['canco_page_builder'] ) && $_POST['canco_page_builder'] != "" ) {
                update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'canco_page_builder' , $_POST['canco_page_builder'] );
            } else {
                if ( isset( $post->ID ) ) {
                    delete_post_meta( $post->ID, 'canco_page_builder' );
                }
            }

            if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
                return $post_id;
            }

            if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
                if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
                    return $post_id;
                }
            } elseif ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
                return $post_id;
            }

            if ( isset ( $this->_meta_box['fields'] ) ) {
                foreach ( $this->_meta_box['fields'] as $field ) {
                    $old = get_post_meta( $post_id, $field['id'], true );
                    $new = $_POST[$field['id']];
                    if ( $new && $new != $old ) {
                        update_post_meta( $post_id, $field['id'], $new );
                    } elseif ( '' == $new && $old ) {
                        delete_post_meta( $post_id, $field['id'], $old );
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        function meta_box_fields( $field, $value ) {

            echo '<div class="apanel-label">', $field['label'], '</div><div class="apanel-section">';

            switch ( $field['type'] ) {
                case 'checkbox':
                    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '"', $value ? ' checked="checked"': '', ' />';
                    break;
                case 'multi-checkbox':
                    if ( isset( $field['options'] ) ) {
                        foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
                            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="', $field['id'],'" value="', $option['value'], '"', in_array( $option['value'], $value ) ? ' checked="checked"': '', ' /><label for="', $option['value'], '">', $option['label'], '</label><br />';
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }

            echo '</div>';

        }

    }

    $canco_product_details = array(
        'id'        => 'canco_product_details',
        'title'     => 'details',
        'pages'     => array( 'post' ),
        'context'   => 'normal',
        'priority'  => 'high',
        'fields'    => array(
            array(
                'id'      => 'canco_product_color',
                'type'    => 'multi-checkbox',
                'label'   => 'colors',
                'options' => array(
                    array(
                        'value' => '#0038a8',
                        'label' => 'blue',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'value' => '#ee2b2c',
                        'label' => 'red',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'value' => '#139f49',
                        'label' => 'green',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'value' => '#000000',
                        'label' => 'black',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'value' => '#dd1176',
                        'label' => 'pink',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'value' => '#e25f33',
                        'label' => 'orange',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );

    new Canco_Meta_Box( $canco_product_details );
```

I'm trying to build a meta box with a bunch of check boxes for my user to choose, and I'm able to make it show on my custom post type edit screen. But the check boxes are not saving... Here's the code for building the check boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `[]` to your field's name:

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="', $field['id'],'[]" ...
```

This will save all of the incoming values, instead of the last one. The reason is that form elements of the same name will override each other:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheck" value="foo"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheck" value="bar"/>
```

Assuming both are checked, on the backend when the form is received, "mycheck" will be `bar`, however:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheck[]" value="foo"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheck[]" value="bar"/>
```

Now, the value of "mycheck" will be an array containing the checked elements' values. So, if both were checked the value would be:

```
Array(
    'foo',
    'bar'
)
```